can't SignUp user in flutter firebase: firebase_auth/channel-error
I am trying to sign up a user using firebase but instead i am getting firebase channel error
following is the code
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todo_fb_provider/models/usermodel.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class SignUpSerivce {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseFirestore fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  Future<void> createUser(BuildContext context, String userId, String userName,
      String name, String password, String gender, String email) async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await _auth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      String uid = userCredential.user!.uid;
      Usermodel usermodel = Usermodel(
          email: email,
          userName: userName,
          userId: userId,
          gender: gender,
          password: password,
          name: name);

      await fireStore.collection('users').doc(uid).set(usermodel.toMap());
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('User Created Successfully')),
      );
      print('User Created');
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Failed with error $e')),
      );
      print(e);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}


I want it to create a user with the provided details but instead i get the following
I/flutter (12898): [firebase_auth/channel-error] "dev.flutter.pigeon.firebase_auth_platform_interface.FirebaseAuthHostApi.createUserWithEmailAndPassword".

all the firebase permissions are set to true

Are you configuring firebase correctly? Check dependencies and versions. Check if you're main.dart is initializing firebase correctly.
Have you added google-service.json in correct folder?

The issue arises by passing Emtpy String to createUserWithEmailAndPassword() method.
Please check your method call and make sure that the strings being passed to your createUser() method are not empty.
Common issues include placing the wrong TextController that is yet to be initialized.

Yes, I hadn’t assigned the initialized TextController to the TextField. Now, the error is resolved.
